# App getting crash when app start on Testflight

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

In versions, 1.1 and 1.2 app runs fine. I have created a new build-1.1 on Version-1.3. The app works fine in debug mode without any crash when I distributed the app to testflight my app getting crashed.
Note: I haven't Enable Device Specific Build.
I configured the provisioning profile and bundle Id correctly.

Don't know what is the issue. If anyone facing the same issue please answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

It could be a lot of reasons! One way to get to the reason:

- When the app crashes, it generates a crash report on the device. Connect the device after the crash to Xcode, open "Devices" window and check the devices crash reports and the console to find out what is happening.

Possible things to try:

- It seems like it's a compiler issue. To verify first change the configuration to Release mode and then install the build locally to your phone. You will get to know where exactly its crashing.
- Are you using the same Build Configuration (Debug/Release) while debugging on a device and the testflight app?

  - If not, it could be because of Optimizations being enabled, or unsupported Linker behavior in the iOS Project options.
  - If yes, try to upload a Debug version of the app into Testflight and retest it